# Stubbing Out Middleware

Tags: node.js, sinon, chai, chai-http

I'm trying to use Sinon to stub out some custom middleware in an express route but it's not working as I expect it to. I expect it to not log "I am authenticating..." and instead log "Stubbed" to the console. It looks like sinon is not stubbing out the middleware correctly.

**test/test.js**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const should = chai.should();
const auth = require('../auth');

const app = require('../app')

describe('My routes', function() {
    let checkTokenStub;
    beforeEach(()=>{
        checkTokenStub = sinon.stub(auth,'checkToken').callsFake(()=>{
            console.log('Stubbed');
        });;
    })
     it('returns hello', function(done) {
            chai.request(app)
                .get('/')
                .set('X-Auth-Token', 'xyz123')
                .end((err,res)=>{
                    res.text.should.be.eql('Hello')

                    done(err)
                })
        });
    });
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
var router = express.Router();
app.use('/', require('./router'));

module.exports = app;
```

**auth.js**

```
exports.checkToken = function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('I am authenticating...')

    var authToken = req.get('x-auth-token');

    if (!authToken)
        return res.sendStatus(401);

    next();
}
```

**router.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router();
auth = require('./auth');

router.get('/', auth.checkToken, function(req, res, next) {
    return res.send('Hello');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sinontest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "sinon": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: try requiring your app after you've stubbed your method. I think the problem is that your routes are configured with the reference to the middleware after you require your app.js, and then you stub your method, but the route is already configured with the original function reference

Comment: Yep. @Gonzalo.- that is it. Thank you, I've been stuck on this for days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Gonzalo.- answered this question in the comments. I had to move the requiring of app to after the stub.

**test.js**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const sinon = require('sinon');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const should = chai.should();
const auth = require('../auth');
let app;


describe('My routes', function() {
    let checkTokenStub;
    before(()=>{
        checkTokenStub = sinon.stub(auth,'checkToken').callsFake((req,res,next)=>{
            console.log('Stubbed');
            next()
        });

        app = require('../app')

    })
     it('returns hello', function(done) {
            chai.request(app)
                .get('/')
                .set('X-Auth-Token', 'xyz123')
                .end((err,res)=>{
                    res.text.should.be.eql('Hello')

                    done(err)
                })
        });
    });
```

Comment: Terrific! callsFake is what I was looking for :)

Comment: How can we do this when we use ES6 import, for me it gets stubed after the middleware is registered so the old one is called. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1117136/akl47